# Isomorphism between two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that  $\langle \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z, +\rangle$ and $\langle U_{n}, {}\cdot{}\rangle$ are isomorphic binary structure where $U_n$ is roots of unity and $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is integers modulo $n$.

I know that for isomorphic binary structure, we define a function between groups and we should check homomorphism property and bijection. But I can not define a function. Please help me, if you have any good idea.

Comment: That's better. Now, if you're stuck on a general problem (like here, "show that for all $n$, something something"), it usually helps to check a few small examples and see if you can get some insight. What about $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_2$ and $U_2$? What about $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ and $U_3$? Can you find isomorhisms there? What about $4$ and $5$? Does that generalize in any way?

Comment: You are right. Thank you. I can define a map between $Z/3Z$ and $U3$ for example : $f(3k)$ = $(3k)^i$ or can not ?

Comment: What are the elements of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, and what are the elements of $U_3$?

Comment: $Z/3Z= {0, 3, 6, 9, 12,....}$ and $U3={1,t, t^{2}}$ where $t=e^{2\pi(i)/3}$

Comment: No, $0, 3, 6, 9, \ldots$ is $3\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. The three elements of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ are $\{\ldots, -3, 0, 3, 6, \ldots\}$ and $\{\ldots,-2, 1, 4, 7, \ldots\}$ and $\{\ldots,-1, 2, 5, 8, \ldots\}$, usually called $[0], [1]$ and $[2]$.

Comment: True. Z/3Z is {0,1,2}

Comment: @Arthur  Can please tell why $2\mathbb{Z}$ does not have negative values, like $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: @jiten I don't know exactly what youre asking here, but $2\Bbb Z$ is the set of all even integers ($3\Bbb Z$ has all the integers that are divisible by $3$), it has infinitely many elements, and many of them (such as $-6$ and $-12$) are negative. On the other hand, $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ has two elements ($\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ has three elements). $2\Bbb Z$ is one of those elements, and that element is also often called $[0]$ or $\bar 0$ (similarly, $3\Bbb Z$ is one of the elements of $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$). It doesn't make sense to classify the elements of $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ as positive or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Outline:

$$U_n=\{1, \zeta,\zeta^2,\cdots, \zeta^{n-1}\}=\langle \zeta \rangle$$ where $\zeta=e^\frac{2 \pi i}{n}$

For a sake of simplicity,  identify $\Bbb Z/ n \Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb Z_n$. Here $\Bbb Z_n =\langle 1 \rangle$. Then the map $$ f:\Bbb Z_n \ni 1^i \mapsto \zeta^i \in U_n$$ is an isomorphism (!). Here $1^n$ means $\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n \;times}$