# Prove that the groups $(\mathbb{Z_n}, +)$ of residue classes modulo $n$ and $(U_\mathbb{n}, \cdot)$ of the $n$-th roots of unity are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

I have to prove that the groups $(\mathbb{Z_n}, +)$ and $(U_\mathbb{n}, \cdot)$ are isomorphic, where $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the set of residue classes modulo $n$:

$$\mathbb{Z_n} = \{\hat{0}, \hat{1}, ..., \widehat{n - 1} \}$$

and $(U_\mathbb{n}, \cdot)$ is the set of $n$-th roots of unity:

$$U_\mathbb{n} = \bigg { \{ } \cos \frac{2 \pi k}{n} + i \sin \frac{2 \pi k}{n} \bigg{|} \hspace{.1cm} k = 0, 1, ..., n - 1  \bigg {\} }$$

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think we could also declare the elements of $U_n$ to be

$$e^{\frac{2 \pi k i}{n}}$$

for $k = 0, 1, ..., n - 1$.

Anyway, so that's what I have to prove. I know that in order to prove that these two groups are isomorphic, I have to find a bijective function $f: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow U_\mathbb{n}$ that has the property:

$$f(x + y) = f(x) \cdot f(y)$$

$\forall \hspace{.1cm} x, y \in \mathbb{Z_n}$. But I cannot come up with any such function. These sets look rather complicated and not only do I have to find a function that has the above property, but I also have to make sure it's bijective. I don't know in which direction to look and how I should search such a function.

I know that this exact same problem has been asked before (e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3025320/592938)) but I really didn't understand that answer, either the function or how it was found.

Comment: In the duplicate you have found, $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$ is exactly what you have said above. So it is very natural and you can understand the answer there.

Comment: How about $f:k\mapsto e^{2\pi k i/n}$?

Comment: Apply first homomorphism theorem to $k\mapsto\exp(2\pi ik/n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should be $f:\Bbb{Z}_n\rightarrow U_n$ where $$f(k)=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n}k).$$
First of all, $f$ is clearly surjective. And since both sets have same number of elements, this implies that $f$ is injective.

To show that $f$ is a homomorphism, let $k,l\in \Bbb{Z}_n$.
$$f(k+l)=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n}(k+l))=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n}k)\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n}l)=f(k)\cdot f(l).$$
Hence $f$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  It suffices to prove that they are both cyclic of order $n$, as there's only one cyclic group of given order (up to isomorphism).